# How to split string by number with JSTL function fn:split?

Tags: java, jsp, split, jstl

I have string `filename3333`. I need to split this string to 2 separate strings `filename` and `3333`. I want to split it with fn:split like that:

```
<c:set var = "filenameParts" value = "${fn:split(filename, 'REGEX')}" />
```

Is it possible to do it with JSTL fn:function by using REGEX or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below :

```
<c:set var = "filenameParts" value = "${fn:split(filename, '(?<=\\D)(?=\\d+\\b)')}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When i try `<c:set var = "filename" value="filename3333" />
  <c:set var = "filenameParts" value = "${fn:split(filename, '(?<=\\D)(?=\\d+\\b)')}" />` it gives me this exception : `IllegalArgumentException: The expression [${fn:split(filename, '((?<=\\D)(?=\\d+\\b)')}] is not valid. Within a quoted String only [\], ['] and ["] may be escaped with [\].`

Comment: you can try `${filename.split(regex above)}` if you on servlet 3.0^.